# Margin of Error?

Tags: probability, statistics

A lab is trying to obtain the result $M$ of an experiment with higher precision. Each execution of the experiment has a cost of $C$. Find the minimum cost for the lab to obtain a result with a margin of error not greater than $\delta$, knowing that the results are independent and have a population standard deviation $\sigma$.

I thought of using $Pr[|\bar{X} - \mu| \leqslant \delta]$ but I can't seem to fit the data in here.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your terminology and notation are undefined and unfamiliar to me. (For example, what is $M$?) However, I think there is a good chance you are dealing with the margin of error of a 95% confidence interval
for the population mean $\mu,$ based on the sample mean $\bar X.$

For normal data, the confidence interval is of the form 
$$\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n},$$ where $\sigma$ is the population
standard deviation, $n$ is the sample size, and $E = 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.
is the margin of error. If you want $E \le \delta,$ then solve for $n$ to
get $n = (1.96\sigma/E)^2.$
Finaly, the cost is $Cn.$

*Notes:* (1) Sometimes, one uses $2.0$ instead of $1.96.$ (2) If the population
standard deviation (SD) $\sigma$ is unknown and has to be estimated by the sample
SD $s,$ then it may be necessary to use Student's t distribution to get
a replacement number for $1.96.$ But if the value of $n > 30,$ then that
adjustment will be too small to fuss with. (3) Please leave a clarifying
note, if I have not correctly guessed what you are requesting.

Comment: I am familiar with all of the concepts you cited, hence my current situation enrolled in an undergrad in Statistics. But I have never seen that notation either. I think M and C are just known numbers but still it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The meaning of $C$ seems clear enough. I wonder if $M$ is alternative notation for sample mean $\bar X,$ which is tedious to write unless you're using some variant of LaTeX. My guess is that my solution is what was intended. It is very standard stuff covered in the vast majority of elementary statistics and research methods textbooks.

Comment: I think I cracked the code... $$E = 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \delta \Rightarrow n \geqslant {\left(\frac{1.96 \sigma}{\delta}\right)}^{2}$$ And if we want the minimum cost, we use $$n = {\left(\frac{1.96 \sigma}{\delta}\right)}^{2}$$ And then we have the minimum cost, which is $C{\left(\frac{1.96 \sigma}{\delta}\right)}^{2}$

Comment: Good. Consistent with what I had in mind.